# Insert an area with decimal values in a CPTXPlotSpace

Tags: core-plot

Everyone!

II'm a new user of CorePlot and I'm needing to insert an area with decimal values in a CPTXPlotSpace, these values should be between 3 parallel CPTScatterPlot straight lines drawn in CPTXPlotSpace.

In "DelegateshouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent" method I can take the "doublePrecisionPlotPoint" and "point" values,  as shown below:

double dataPoint[2];

[space doublePrecisionPlotPoint:dataPoint numberOfCoordinates:2 forEvent:event];

```
NSLog(@"Data Point (X) : %f, Data Point (Y) %f ", dataPoint[0], dataPoint[1]);

NSLog(@"Point Cordenada (X) : %f, Ponto Cordenada (Y) %f ", point.x, point.y);
```

Now what I need is to get a new median value between these parallel lines in this event, when the user hovers the cursor between those lines.  Below follows a sample image:

[image]

Anyone have already come across this?

Comment: This sounds like a geometry problem, but it's not entirely clear what you're asking. Do you want to calculate a point on one of the lines or determine which line is closest to the point?

Comment: Hello Eric. Thanks so much for the comment. What I`m needing is to determinate which line is closest to the point like you said. Can you help me ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the distance between and your point and each line and determine which one is closest. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) for details of the math.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I've already thought about to do that, but i was wondering if there is another coreplot solution. Thanks a lot.